# Wireless Broadcom 4313 Ubuntu 14.04 connection established but no traffic

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, 14.04, broadcom

another Broadcom 4313 issue. Sorry, but after trying to fix it for several hours, you might have a quick look and help me out!

`~$ lspci -nn -d 14e4:
24:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4727] (rev 01)`

and:

```
` ~$ rfkill list all
0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
2: hp-wwan: Wireless WAN
Soft blocked: yes
Hard blocked: no
3: hp-gps: GPS
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
4: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no`
```

and:

```
~$ lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
ctr                    13049  1 
ccm                    17773  1 
arc4                   12608  2 
brcmsmac              563041  0 
b43                   387371  0 
cordic                 12574  1 brcmsmac
ssb                    62379  1 b43
brcmutil               15618  1 brcmsmac
bcma                   52096  3 b43,brcmsmac
mac80211              626511  2 b43,brcmsmac
cfg80211              484040  3 b43,brcmsmac,mac80211
bnep                   19624  2 
rfcomm                 69160  0 
bluetooth             395423  10 bnep,rfcomm
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     46207  1 
snd_hda_codec_idt      54645  1 
uvcvideo               80885  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      13216  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13362  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_core         40664  1 uvcvideo
videodev              134688  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
hp_wmi                 14062  0 
sparse_keymap          13948  1 hp_wmi
intel_rapl             18773  0 
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    14205  0 
cdc_mbim               13176  0 
intel_powerclamp       14705  0 
coretemp               13435  0 
kvm                   451511  0 
cdc_ncm                24511  1 cdc_mbim
usbnet                 43913  2 cdc_mbim,cdc_ncm
snd_hda_intel          52355  3 
mii                    13934  1 usbnet
snd_hda_codec         192906  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel
cdc_wdm                19053  1 cdc_mbim
snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
cdc_acm                28803  0 
snd_pcm               102099  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_page_alloc         18710  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            30144  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                61560  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
crct10dif_pclmul       14289  0 
crc32_pclmul           13113  0 
ghash_clmulni_intel    13216  0 
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
aesni_intel            55624  2 
snd_timer              29482  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
aes_x86_64             17131  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    13286  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               14951  1 lrw
glue_helper            13990  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            13597  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20359  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
mei_me                 18627  0 
i915                  783485  4 
snd                    69238  17 snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
mei                    82274  1 mei_me
joydev                 17381  0 
lpc_ich                21080  0 
serio_raw              13462  0 
drm_kms_helper         52758  1 i915
drm                   302817  5 i915,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit           13413  1 i915
soundcore              12680  1 snd
tpm_infineon           17372  0 
hp_accel               26012  0 
video                  19476  1 i915
lis3lv02d              20156  1 hp_accel
input_polldev          13896  1 lis3lv02d
wmi                    19177  1 hp_wmi
mac_hid                13205  0 
parport_pc             32701  1 
ppdev                  17671  0 
lp                     17759  0 
parport                42348  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
ahci                   25819  2 
psmouse               102222  0
```

and:

```
~$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     1      0        0 eth0
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Nico

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

Supply your password, dots will not be visible. According to me, your bluetooth and wifi are soft blocked.

Try combination of function keys, if you are using a laptop.

it will solve your problem, I think, your wireless is soft blocked.